# How to disable or make fields unpublished, but not delete them

Tags: entities

I have some fields I need to disable from user registration, but no delete them, just make them unpublished or disable them temporarily, is there a way to do that?

[image]

Comment: admin/config/people/accounts/display

Comment: That's for display, I need it gone from user registration and editing form

Comment: You'll have to use hook_form_alter

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution offhand is to make the fields non-required for registration. And then setup the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module temporarily to not give `Edit permission` to Role(s) you don't want to see those fields.

> The Field Permissions module allows site administrators to set
>   field-level permissions to edit, view and create fields on any entity.

Comment: I tried the field permissions , doesn't work, field still shows up....

Comment: It seems that you didn't properly install and configure the module then.

Comment: I installed it and configured properly, 4 little red X's showing disabled for the field in question. I turned off ALL permissions, including administrator. When adding users from Admin backend, the field still shows up...

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively a shameless (but effective) hack is to use [Field Group](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_group) to create a fieldset with a specific CSS class. Make sure the class has a `display: none;` property.  Put the field inside that fieldset, and sit back and relax.

Something else you could try is [Display Suite](https://www.drupal.org/project/ds) "Extras" (/admin/structure/ds/list/extras). Try using the "Hidden region" option (not sure if it works only for view or both view and form).

Now, if your visibility option is temporary and dependent on other factors ( other fields, etc), you will need to write a custom module or use something like, for example, [Field Conditional States](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_conditional_state).

Comment: Every CMS in the world has "dissable" and "unpublish" options...hard to be leive this is impossible with Drupal?...

Comment: See my edited answer. Field Conditional States should work to disable visibility. Also, I'm surprised Field Permissions did not work for you. This module allows you to set edit permission to specific roles.

Comment: More: Drupal has a lot of flexibility, but some seemingly simple things required some labor. For example, a common way of "disabling" a field in a form is to create a custom module and use `hook_form_alter`. Seems difficult but it's not. Many tutorials online.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Display Suite](http://drupal.org/project/ds) and move the fields to the "Hidden" section. This would remove them from the form, and you can also do this with any content type.

Comment: That only works for display. I need the field to not be published on user form.

Comment: You can do it on the "manage field" as well.